# Install canonical-livepatch had failure

Tags: canonical-livepatch

I can not install `canonical-livepatch`.

Writing command line in terminal:

```
sudo snap install canonical-livepatch
```

and the output:

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Download snap "ubuntu-core" (423) from channel "stable" (received an unexpected http response code (401) when trying to download https://public.apps.ubuntu.com/download-snap/b8X2psL1ryVrPt5WEmpYiqfr5emixTd7_423.snap)
```

How to fix?

My platform: Unity Ubuntu 16.10.

Answer (score 3):

You must use LTS release for canonical-livepatch.

> Want to apply critical kernel security fixes without rebooting your system? The Canonical Livepatch Service for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS reduces planned or unplanned downtime while maintaining compliance and security <sup>[Canonical Livepatch Service](https://www.ubuntu.com/server/livepatch)</sup>